# Aiogram 2.25.1 не работает callback_query_handler с inline кнопками

Tags: python, callback, aiogram-2.x

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup


bot = Bot(token="token")

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

kbbk = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='tap on me', callback_data='www'))

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):    
    await message.answer('!', reply_markup=kbbk)

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def cback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if str(call.data) == 'www':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.from_user.id, text='adasdasd')

 
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Я запустил ваш код на aiogram 2.25.1 и у меня все работает

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, начинаю думать что дело в самом боте

Comment: Попробуйте создать новое виртуальное окружение, с новым python файлом, и запустить его через терминал

Comment: Бесполезно(, кнопка все равно не работает

Comment: И нет никаких ошибок? Попробуйте еще создать нового бота, и попробовать запустить код с токеном нового бота

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось сменой телеграм аккаунта и созданием нового бота